# Python PySerial, How to Open Serial Ports?

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm trying to run this example program from the PySerial Documentation for opening serial ports. Source: http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html
I tried running the code in both python version 2.7 and 3.4 but still get same error.

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial(0)  # open first serial port
>>> print ser.name          # check which port was really used
>>> ser.write("hello")      # write a string
>>> ser.close()             # close port
```

I get the following error after running the second line of code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    ser = serial.Serial(0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 38, in __init__
    SerialBase.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 282, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 66, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %r: %r" % (self.portstr,     ctypes.WinError()))
SerialException: could not open port 'COM1': WindowsError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

Comment: Have you tried to use another program like HyperTerminal or the included MiniTerm to connect to the serial ports to make sure they're available? And what OS are you using?

Comment: Does your system actually have a COM1 port?

Comment: How do I find out if my system has a COM1 port?

Comment: How do I use MiniTerm?

Comment: You can use the code mentioned [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/07/31/listing-all-serial-ports-on-windows-with-python) to check your registry for serial ports defined

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like COM1 is not available (it doesn't exist or it's already being used).
I made this little scripts for listing available COM ports.

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial()
for ns in xrange(101): 
    try:
        ser.port=ns
        ser.open()
        print "COM"+str(ns+1)+" available"
        ser.close()

    except serial.SerialException:
        print "COM"+str(ns+1)+" NOT available"
```

Remember that the COM port number is the number you pass to serial +1 (serial.Serial(0) opens COM1, serial.Serial(1) opens COM2, etc.)

Comment: You can make your loop more pythonic by using: "for ns in xrange(101):"  in "place of while True:"  and eliminate the lines of manual initializing, incrementing and test/break required in your loop.